# Does PHP automatically convert numbers to strings?

Tags: php, javascript, json, casting

I am using dojo and ajax to send a time stamp to PHP, which does a database check, then returns  the time stamp for debugging purposes. When I send this time stamp, it's a number, when it is returned, it is a string. Is there a specific reason for this? What should I do to avoid this (cast to int in PHP, fix via JSON, or cast to int in javascript)

Here is the Dojo code

```
dojo.xhrGet({
 url: 'database/validateEmail.php',
 handleAs: "json",
 content: {
 email : 'George.Hearst@Pinkerton.dw',
 time: 0
 },
 load: function(args) {/*SEE BELOW*/}
});
```

Here is the PHP script

```
<?php

/**
 ** connect to the MySQL database and store the return value in $con
 *
 */
$con = mysql_pconnect("localhost:port", "username", "password");

/**
 ** handle exceptions if we could not connect to the database
 *
 */
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

/**
 ** Create table query
 *
 */
mysql_select_db("portal", $con);

/**
 ** Get user entered e-mail
 *
 */
$emailQuerry = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT EMAIL FROM user WHERE EMAIL='" . $_GET["email"] . "'")) == 1;

/**
 ** Whether successful or not, we will be returning the time stampe (this is used to determine whether there were any changes between the time a request
 ** was sent, and when this response was returned.
 *
 */
 $result['time'] = $_GET["time"];

/**
 ** Currently only checks to see if the two values were provided. Later, will have to check against passwords
 *
 */
if ($emailQuerry) {
    $result['valid'] = true;
}
else {
    $result['valid'] = false;
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

And finally the load function left blank above

```
load: function(args) {
 console.log(localArgs.time + ' v ' + args.time);
 console.log(localArgs.time === args.time);
 console.log(localArgs.time == args.time);
}
```

The output of which is

```
0 v 0
false
true
```

Comment: @Blender -- all the password info is still in the history ^_^

Comment: You can replace this whole block: `if ($emailQuerry) {... }` with just `$result['valid'] = $emailQuerry;`

Comment: @Neal, better in the history than out in the open. Thanks for telling erryone ;)

Comment: @Blender lol i flagged it for a mod.

Comment: @Neal: Same here. Can they magically do things like this?

Comment: It's only the local credentials. Is it really that big of a deal?

Comment: @Blender haha no idea ^_^ can't hurt to try :-)

Comment: @MichaelMyers it might be if another one of this OP's office mates sees it...

Comment: That wasn't actually my password...it was my attempt at humor.

Comment: @Blender I am really really knew to PHP. I would appreciate links to advanced tutorials. Almost all PHP tutorials talk about the most basic topics such as for loops, variables, strings, GET, POST...but thanks for the tip

Comment: @puk: The answer you chose is incorrect. Could you reconsider your choice?

Comment: @Muu, how can the OP's choice be incorrect?

Comment: @puk, I see what you did there >.<

Comment: @Blender: see Thai's comment.

Comment: @Muu Josh's answer technically doesn't work for me since `GET` returns a string to begin with. Both Neal and yourself are correct. His is client side, while yours is server side.

Comment: @puk: Neal's "parseInt" approach is valid, however his statement that it's necessary and that json_encode encodes everything as a string is false.

Comment: @Muu yes I noticed that too. What am I supposed to do here? The correct part of his answer is what I want. Should I request that he edit his answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_encode` encodes all variables as a string.

So the javascript will see it as a string.

So in the javascript you *could* use `parseInt(...)`

Comment: Is json the best/preferred/accepted way carry out what I am doing right now? I would prefer to do things correctly from the beginning. Thanks

Comment: @puk it is the perferred way for me (if that is enough for you ^_^)

Comment: `json_encode` does __not__ encode all values as a string. Numbers, true, false, and null are all encoded correctly using json_encode. The actual cause is that all _scalar_ `$_GET` parameters are string, so it should be converted to number there: `$result['time'] = (float)$_GET["time"];`

Comment: @Thai, I'll just convert it client side then.

Comment: @Neal I like your answer but I am coming under considerable heat for choosing it since some of your statements are inaccurate. Could you please mention `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` and change 'have to use' to 'could use'

Answer (score 2):

You can use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to output your numbers from PHP (post-encode), with the [JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) option.

Comment: This is good to know, however, `GET` returns a string always, so this approach does not apply here.

Answer (score 1):

To send an integer out as an integer is simple - provide json_encode with one!
Put '(int)' around anything that you want converting.

Here's an example:

```
echo json_encode(array(1, 2, 3));
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3]
```

And another:

```
$a = '123';
echo json_encode(array($a, (int) $a));
```

Output:

```
["123",123]
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct, but I'm going to go with Neal's b/c I think it's easier to do these calculations client side. If anyone believes that this must be done server side, I will consider changing the correct answer back over to muu.

Comment: @puk: Neil's method is valid however he is wrong that it's the only way.